# "Invalid Index" error in Scilab

Tags: matlab, scilab

I'm using the following code:

```
for t = linspace(0,2,500)   

   x(t) = 1+ t^2;   
   y(t) = 2*t;  
   r(t) = sqrt((x(t))^2+(y(t))^2);  

   radius = 1.6

   if r(t) > 0.999*radius & r(t) < 1.001*radius then
       solucion = t;

   end
end;

disp(solucion, "the solution is:")
```

Which works fine with `t` > 1 and different radius values.

But I get `error 21: Invalid index` when `t` takes values between 0 and 1.

I need to work with those values as well. How do I handle this?

Comment: If this works like MATLAB you can only index stuff with positive integers. Use an array (e.g. `0:0.01:1`) and access that with your loop variable, which are integers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just so this shows up as answered in the overview:

Array indices in Scilab and MATLAB have to be positive integers (or logicals, but that is definitely not what you want here). If you need your `t` to vary over a range starting at 0, always write `x(t+1)`. If you need non- integer values, still iterate over integers and compute the non-integral values from the loop index.

Comment: Didn't know "0" isn't a valid index :)